# R: Lubridate outputformat DMY

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

I was studying the [cheat-sheet](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf) and other ressources, however I always found examples using `lubridate`from `tidyverse`putting me the result date into the format Y-M-D

For example having in the raw data the following:

`01.06.2016` whhich says First July of 2016 and running:
`Date.last.Contact = lubridate::dmy(Date.last.Contact)` giving me `2016-06-01`

I just want the german format like 01-06-2016. I have to mutate it into date-format to calculate the minimal date od some datarows in my r-script.
I was looking for a parameter where I can specify the output format, however I did not find the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
format(ymd(20200102), "%d.%m.%Y")
```

output:

```
"02.01.2020"
```

It is simply about the way you format the output string that is create from the date vector.

Comment: oh well i was not thinking that this would be so easy many thanks!